# iOS offline post a toast from background

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5, ios6

I'm not sure if an iOS app can post a notification from the background without internet connection? (so this is not a push notification, just to post from phone)

Example: An iOS app that plays music in background can prompt user how long the user has listened to music from background.

Comment: Could I consider you are asking if you can prompt a local notification in an app with `audio` background mode ?

Answer (score 0):

The local notifications in iOS can help you to fix the problem. May be [this tutorial](http://www.devfright.com/uilocalnotification-tutorial/) helps you.

Comment: Could you maybe also summarize the content of the link? It may get lost at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use local notification, please see the below code for local notification,

```
NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date]
      dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc]
      init];
if (notifyAlarm)
{
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = alertTime;
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    notifyAlarm.soundName = @"bell_tree.mp3";
    notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"Staff meeting in 30 minutes";
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
}
```

With these requirements in the mind, the following code creates an NSDate object based on the current date and time plus 10 seconds. This date object is then used to schedule a notification with no repeats, a text message and the sound from the audio file